# Part Suggestions For ECG Project

Tags: microcontroller, accelerometer, ecg, portable

I am planning to build a project around https://www.sparkfun.com/products/12650 to take an ECG while I am on a roller-coaster (not for medical purposes, just for fun).

The following points are (additional) requirements:

1. To capture the data, I need to write them onto an SD card or some other memory device.
2. The device should support wifi so I can have a live feed on my mobile phone. So one possibility would be an ESP 32 or ESP 8266.
3. Another great addition would be an acceleration sensor......
4. Because this should be useable on a roller-coaster, a power bank for mobile phones (except for very small ones) and a stationary power source are both not useable. The power source (maybe a battery?) should last about 12 hours. If this is possible with a small power bank, I will use one of these, because I can ignore the protections against discharging and such problems completely. So that decision depends on the energy consumption of the build and the possibility to use an USB cable for connecting the two.
5. The whole device can not take up a lot of space (it should fit below my shirt or so, to not fly around freely, I will 3D print a casing).

I experimented with ESP and raspberry pi before, so I know how to program and connect additional devices to them, but I never tried to build a "portable" device at all (only built stationary so far) and never used something from SparkFun's "ecosystem" before.

To come to a conclusion, it would be great, if you can help me finding the right parts for that project. If you have a better ECG solution, I am not bound to this item linked at the top.

I am waiting for your answers and hoping, that you can help me

Comment: Before you think of designing anything make a list of all your assumptions into a spec like signal level, BW, galvanic skin response from motion or IR + Red LED transmission loss in finger with vibration..  etc etc...the. Test your ECS cct before thinking of anything else. .the rest is easy. You might want to build the sensors into a chest band or headband or wrist where galvanic skin noise voltage from changes in electrode pressure are reduced.

Comment: The ECG does not work with IR light like the most that you find, it is a "real" ECG (well better than these finger sensors, but not as good as the ones you find at the hospital) and should do, what it is supposed to. Here you have a video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sP_-f5nsOEo (I only want to record the signals, the rest is done later with my computer, when I am back at home)

Comment: You will want to use RLD guard signal too and measure your SNR with muscle artifact noise and galvanic skin response noise while pretending to get rock n rolled.what would to expect BER <1% ? 0.1% 10%? See what I mean?? You aren’t laying still in a bed. My finger HB monitor works well in 2 seconds very accurately as long as the sensor grabs onto any digit without touching something else but with lots of motion. $50